# Google Maps API V3 - Display pictures inside InfoWindow based on attribute values from MySQL database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have InfoWindow that displayed values from MySQL, but now I would like that inside InfoWindow are displayed pictures base on attribute values from MySQL.
For example if "swimming" attribute have value 1 inside InfoWindow will be displayed picture http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/ratoca/ratoca1207/ratoca120700086/14399447-swimming-sign.jpg , and if "swimming" attribute have value 0 no picture will be displayed.

My current code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href="Free-Camping/free_camping_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Free Camping</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

<!--
//<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {

      "1": {
        icon: 'Free-Camping/markers/BeachCampingSite.png',
      },

      "2": {
        icon: 'Free-Camping/markers/BushCampingSite.png',
      },

      "3": {
        icon: 'Free-Camping/markers/ParkForestReserve.png',
      },

      "4": {
        icon: 'Free-Camping/markers/PrivateCampingSite.png',
      },

      "5": {
        icon: 'Free-Camping/markers/RoadsideRestArea.png',
      },

      "6": {
        icon: 'Free-Camping/markers/NewLocationMarker.png',
      }

    };


    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.878994,134.018553),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("Free-Camping/free_camping_phpsql.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var street = markers[i].getAttribute("street");
          var locality = markers[i].getAttribute("locality");
          var description = markers[i].getAttribute("description");
          var image = markers[i].getAttribute("image");
          var toilet = markers[i].getAttribute("toilet");
          var bbq = markers[i].getAttribute("bbq");
          var able = markers[i].getAttribute("able");
          var tentok = markers[i].getAttribute("tentok");
          var caravanok = markers[i].getAttribute("caravanok");
          var dumppoint = markers[i].getAttribute("dumppoint");
          var shade = markers[i].getAttribute("shade");
          var water = markers[i].getAttribute("water");
          var swimming = markers[i].getAttribute("swimming");
          var fishing = markers[i].getAttribute("fishing");
          var hiking = markers[i].getAttribute("hiking");
          var mobileok = markers[i].getAttribute("mobileok");
          var name2 = markers[i].getAttribute("name2");
          var email = markers[i].getAttribute("email");
          var lat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
          var lng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng");

          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

         var html = '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">' + name 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left "> Street: &nbsp;' + street 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left "> Locality: &nbsp;' + locality +  '</br>'

         //Lat and Lng 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Lat: &nbsp;' + lat 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Lng: &nbsp;' + lng + '</br>'         
         + '<img src="Free-Camping/images/'+image+'" width=200 height=150>' + '</br>' 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Description: &nbsp;' + description 

         // Checkbox
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Toilet: &nbsp;' + toilet 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  BBQ: &nbsp;' + bbq 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Table: &nbsp;' + able
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Tent: &nbsp;' + tentok 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Caravan: &nbsp;' + caravanok
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Dumppoint: &nbsp;' + dumppoint
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Shade: &nbsp;' + shade 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Water: &nbsp;' + water 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Swimming: &nbsp;' + swimming
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Fishing: &nbsp;' + fishing 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Hiking: &nbsp;' + hiking 
         + '<h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left ">  Mobile: &nbsp;' + mobileok + '</a>';

          var icon = customIcons[category] || {};

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}


//]]>
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>

</head>

<body onload="load();">

<div id="main_layer" style="position:absolute; left:50%; top:25px; width:788px; height:1600px; margin-left: -390px;">

<div id="map_layer" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:780px; height:595px;" class="map_frame">
<div id="map" style="position:absolute; top:45px; width:760px; height:500px; margin-left: 10px; "></div>
<div id="legend" style="position:absolute; top:550px; width:760px; height:45px; margin-left: 10px; " class="legend_text"><img src="Free-Camping/markers/BeachCampingSite.png" width="32" height="37"><span class="legend_text">Beach Camping Site&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="Free-Camping/markers/BushCampingSite.png" width="32" height="37">Bush Camping Site&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="Free-Camping/markers/ParkForestReserve.png" width="32" height="37">Park Forest Reserve&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="Free-Camping/markers/PrivateCampingSite.png" width="32" height="37"> PrivateCampingSite&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="Free-Camping/markers/RoadsideRestArea.png" width="32" height="37">Roadside Rest Area</span></div>
</div>


<div id="form" style="position:absolute; left:0px; margin-left: 0px; top:603px; width:788px; height:980px; background-color: #f4f4f4; layer-background-color: #f4f4f4; border: 1px none #000000;" class="form">
<form action="free_camping_insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="form" style="position:absolute; left:14; top:0px; width:760px; height:275px;" class="form2">
  <p align="center" class="headers">Add a New Free Camping Site</p>
  <p align="center"><span class="text">Your Name:</span>      <input type="text" name="name2" />
      <br>
      <br>

      <span class="text">Your Email:</span>  
      <input type="text" name="email" />
  <br>
  <br>

  <span class="text">Campsite name:</span>  
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <br>
  <br>

  <span class="text">Type of Campsite:</span>
  <select name="category">
    <option value="1">Beach Camping Site</option>
    <option value="2">Bush Camping Site</option>
    <option value="3">Park Forest Reserve</option>
    <option value="4">Private Camping Site</option>
    <option value="5">Roadside Rest Area</option>
  </select>
  <p align="center" class="text">
  <label>Upload Picture</label>
 <input type="file" name="image" /><br />
    </div>

<div id="form" style="position:absolute; left:14; top:275px; width:760px; height:150px;" class="form2">
  <p align="center" class="headers">Select Campsite Amenities</p>
  <p align="center"><img src="Free-Camping/images2/AmenitiesIcons.png" width="682" height="44">   </p>

  <div id="checkbox1" style="position:absolute; left:50px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="toilet" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox2" style="position:absolute; left:108px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bbq" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox3" style="position:absolute; left:165px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="able" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox4" style="position:absolute; left:223px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tentok" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox5" style="position:absolute; left:281px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="caravanok" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox6" style="position:absolute; left:338px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="dumppoint" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox7" style="position:absolute; left:398px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="shade" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox8" style="position:absolute; left:454px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="water" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox9" style="position:absolute; left:512px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="swimming" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox10" style="position:absolute; left:570px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="fishing" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox11" style="position:absolute; left:629px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hiking" value="1">
  </div>

  <div id="checkbox12" style="position:absolute; left:687px; top:102px; width:25px; height:25px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mobileok" value="1">
  </div>

  <p align="center"><br>
</div>

<div id="form" style="position:absolute; left:14; top:440px; width:760px; height:525px;" class="form2"> 
  <div align="center"><span class="headers">Description of the Campsite </span><span class="text">(tell as a bit about the site)</span>    </p>
  </div>
  <p align="center">    <textarea name="description" cols="85" rows="7" class="borders_around_form_boxes"></textarea>
    <br>
    </p>
  <p align="center" class="headers">Location of the Free Campsite</p>
  <p align="center" class="text">Enter the GPS coordinates in the boxes or click the button to create a new marker which you can drag and drop on the map. </p>
  <div align="center"><span class="text">Latitude:</span>          <input type="text" name="lat" />
          <br>
          <br>
          <span class="text">Longitude:</span>        
          <input type="text" name="lng" />
        <br>
        <br>

                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />


      </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea where to start?

Best,
Darko

Comment: You can create the infowindow, or the entire function in PHP and then push it to javascript. Hope this gives you a better idea?

Comment: I know that I can create PHP function something like - `if ( $row['9'] == 1 ) {
  echo "<td>".$img."</td>";
} else {
  echo "<td>Image Not Available.</td>";
}`; but I do not know how to call this function inside Infowindow (I tried but I always got Error).